# Egit is installed (came with Juno), but does not show at all

Tags: eclipse-plugin, egit, eclipse-juno, jgit

I want to use GIT in eclipse, and preferably EGit, for it's support from the eclipse community itself. However, despite eclipse claiming the required plugins are installed, it does not appear in the perspectives, import and settings menu's.

I am using Eclipse Juno for Java EE, and have confirmed the following installs:
[image: Installed features]
When I update software, there are no more updates available. When I go to the repository for Egit, or JGit for that matter, eclipse tells me the plugins are already installed.

Window > Preferences > Team contains no Git item, only CVS and SVN.
Import project contains no Git option.
Perspective window contains no Git repo option.

Comment: Very strange. Do you see any errors in the Error Log view or in the `.metadata/.log` file in your workspace directory?

Comment: I would check but just a minute ago I decided to do a clean reinstall so I can't check anymore. Thanks for thinking along!

Comment: I also faced similar issue on Luna. It was working fine but stopped working after I installed "Eclipse Copyright Tool" plugin. The -clean option worked!

Answer (score 19):

Had the same problem in Eclipse Luna

Looking into the error log, I found:

```
org.eclipse.egit.ui
Error
Fri Feb 27 15:36:06 CET 2015
FrameworkEvent ERROR

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.egit.ui [844]
Bundle was not resolved because of a uses contraint violation.
```

Starting eclipse with the `-clean` command line option fixed the problem for me.

Comment: It worked for me on MacBook Pro, El Capitan. You have to execute the Eclipse from the command line. Something like <path to folder where the Eclipse is installed>/Eclipse.app/contents/MacOS/eclipse -clean . After that, you can run the Eclipse normally from an icon or Spotlight.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by running Eclipse as root user and installing the plugins again. Then I ran Eclipse under my normal user account and it was fine - everything showed up.

Version: 3.8.1
Build id: debbuild

Answer (score 2):

Checking the log file of eclipse could always helps you to address this kind of problems.

I also had the same problem with Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2), I fixed the problem by downgrade the version of EGit from 4.0.1 to 3.7.1.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced similar problem and ran eclipse from `CMD -> c:\eclipse\eclipse.exe -clean`
and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had hoped for an easy solution, so I would not have to do a reïnstall of eclipse meaning I'd have to reïnstall plugins and check all my settings etc. again.. I have to work though, so I did a clean install of eclipse (wiped it all), and got me a copy of 64-bit Juno for Java EE which came without EGit/JGit installed. Installed it from the repo and it works now.

Shame we couldn't figure this out, but the coding must go on!

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem with Eclise Juno. After unistalling the Egit plugin and reinstalling , it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Eclipse Mars 2. 
Fixed that by installing the version 4.0 of EGit from here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ#Where_can_I_find_older_releases_of_EGit.3F

Answer (score 0):

In my case, JDK was a problem. I had JDK 1.6.0_27 installed and changed this to jdk1.8.0_111. Then it works well.