# Push Github respiratory using Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.1

Tags: eclipse, github

I'm trying to push my Github respiratory, but when I was following the instructions (http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#GitHub_Tutorial), I couldn't find the Team->Remote->Push option.

Could I have some help, please?

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of the _Team_ right-click menu to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

If it is completely missing (meaning it is not simply "grayed out"), that could mean you don't have EGit installed at all in [your current Eclipse distribution](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php?release=oxygen).

But if that option is just inactive, see "[Eclipse/Egit, Push to Remote menu choice is grayed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10662106/6309)" and do add a remote, for you to push to.

Comment: Or you need to restart Eclipse with the `-clean` option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34101660/6309